# I want to import an excel file to mysql using python 3 and flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to import an excel file to mysql using python 3 and flask
but I don't know how to load the file from my mysql to my base when I click on the load button
if someone is kind to tell me how to achieve it

Comment: Thanks for coming to SO. This question is very broad and it isn't going to get you useful answers. You should include any code you have now, and split it up to narrow down the question. There are several distinct steps: creating the upload form; getting the file to upload properly (where do you put it? how big is it?); converting the Excel file into a Python data structure; creating/populating/adding the instances to the database.

Comment: I am using python flasky I want to load the file of escel to my mysql base the alumos table which has the fields email address names  
the file is excel and I want to click on the upload button to save the same fields names email address of the excel file to the mysql database 
I already have the whole connection to the raw tables but to make life more for the end user instead of loading one by one it would be easier with the excel.
If someone is kind to tell me how to do it, you would like to read how to read the excel and send it to mysql.
Thank you